# Filezilla doesn't run vscode

Tags: ftp, editor, filezilla, visual-studio-code, flatpak

When using the FileZilla client as an application directory ([link](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1)), I can `right-click` an html file on a remote server → `View/Edit` and it will open in my predefined editor (e.g. VSCode).

BUT if I use the FileZilla flatpak version, then I get the following error:

> The file 'index.html' cannot be opened: The associated program
> (/usr/bin/code) could not be found. Please check your filetype
> associations.

I can run `/usr/bin/code` from the command line, but it doesn't work with FileZilla.

Comment: It could be a confinement issue, flatpak/Filezilla does have direct access to launch any program from `/usr/bin/ *` , try another program same location and also another editor installed from flatpak . You  may end up with bug report .

Answer (score 0):

In "Ubuntu Software" list, there is two FileZilla.
One of them is FileZilla(Unofficial). 
If you have installed that, please remove the unofficial one, and install the other one. 
That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want add for php add `php /snap/bin/code`
[filezilla filetype associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwCbo.png)